Firebase Cloud Function Ends by TimeOut rather than with Status OK
I have just implemented a payment gateway in my application. The final transaction status from the gateway is received at my redirect_url which I have set as one of my Google Firebase HTTPS Cloud Functions. The URL goes something like this:
https://*******.cloudfunctions.net/abcd
I don't think this process has been used before by anyone and hence I am worried. The architecture runs great and the transaction completes successfully with the Cloud Function Correctly extracting the status. But the problem is that, when I checked the cloud function logs, I found that this function never ends with a Status OK. It is always:
"Function execution took 55636 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'"
The code goes like this:
exports.ccavRes = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    var ccavEncResponse = ''
    var ccavResponse = ''
    var workingKey = ****** 
    var ccavPOST:any = ''

    const md5 = *****//Hashing step;
    const keyBase64 = *****//;

    // Initializing Vector and then convert in base64 string
    const ivBase64 = *******
    
    ccavEncResponse = req.rawBody.toString()
    ccavPOST = qs.parse(ccavEncResponse);
    const encryption = *****
    ccavResponse = ********
    const params = ccavResponse.split("&");
    let map = new Map<any, any>();
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
      var parts = params[i].split('=');
        map.set(parts[0],parts[1].substr(0, parts[1].length))
    }
    
    const order_id = map.get('order_id')
    const order_status = map.get('order_status')
    const database = admin.database().ref()

    await database.child(*****).child(order_id).child("Status").set(order_status)


    
    return res.send('OK')
})

I have tried adding res.send() before return as per the Firebase Documentation. But that gives a compilation error:
Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Response'
The code is written in typescript.
Even if I do a
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
import * as _ from 'lodash'
import { google } from 'googleapis'

exports.ccavRes = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

 return res.send('Timeout complete')

 })

The compilation error remain,

You definitely need to send a response to the caller in order to terminate the function without timing out.  Please edit the question to show the exact code that uses res.send so we can see that you're doing it correctly.

I have added the res.send. But this one does not compile with the error:
Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Response'

Please edit the question to show all of the code of the function, including your imports.  We should be able to take the code you have, copy it, and run it for ourselves without modification.  I'd also suggest making the function as simple as possible - perhaps a function that doesn't nothing at all except send a basic response.  That way we can narrow down the specific lines of code that are problematic without worrying about anything else.

I have added an extra few lines at the bottom. Hope that helps

Your new function doesn't declare a res variable, but attempts to use it. I don't think that would work at all, and generate a completely different error.

@DougStevenson that was a typo. the rest of the comment stands. Please read response as res

Given that it was a typo, it seems to me that maybe you didn't actually try to build or run the function (otherwise you would have observed the error)? Anyway, I copied the code into a new project, installed the modules you listed, and didn't see a problem. So the problem must be with your project setup.  Please edit the question to show the steps you take to create a new project from scratch (using firebase init) and include this code.  Make sure that you are able to build the project with npm run build.

@DougStevenson in TypeScript even if I do not compile the res.send() error appear. It seems to me it is a TypeScript error. (I can now see that there are a number of errors reported on this issue).
I dont think it is a Firebase error as my project is a full blown project, live and has been running without any issue for the last one year with around 46 other cloud functions. The payment gateway is a new feature that I was trying to add

Without specific instructions on how to reproduce a project from scratch that exhibits this error, I don't think you're likely to get very good help on the issue.  I'm certainly not able to see the problem.

there can't be any reason ... ,do you have any other function  of  onRequest previously running ? also did you try by closing the editor and restart ?

@DougStevenson please see if the following error helps you:
Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<Response>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: Request, resp: Response)

Hi @oTwo, The information is not enough , As DougStevenson already commented ,Please share instructions on how to reproduce a project from scratch that exhibits this error .
